# От чего зависит и как формируется SHA1 под Android?

Tags: android, google-api, sha1

Делаю приложение использующее сервис google. Который требует контрольную сумму сертификата разработчика(SHA1). Когда я работаю на одном компе, потом гружу код в GIT и продолжаю кодить на другом компе используя этот же репозирорий то на обоих ПК SHA1 отличается. Что приводит к тому, что когда я компилю apk на одном ПК то SHA1 совпадает с тем что я зарегистрировал на console.developers и приложение работает. Когда запускаю на втором то приложение не работает и надо на console.developers заново менять SHA1. Плюс на каждом ПК AndroidStudio просит переустановить app.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию при сборке debug версии приложения оно подписывается debug ключом. Обычно он находится по адресу `C:/User/user_name/.android` и генерируется автоматически. Логично что на разных машинах эти ключи будут отличаться.

Для того чтобы с разных компьютеров работали сервисы необходимо в консоль добавить ключи с обоих компьютеров. Переустановить приложение просит по причине того, что подписи у приложений разные.

В случае когда вы готовите релизную сборку, то на всех машинах приложение должно быть подписано одни и тем же ключом, и тогда в этом случае в консоль необходимо так же добавить этот релизный ключ.

Однако можно избежать постоянного добавления дебаг ключей в консоль если на разных машинах использовать один и тот же debug ключ. Сделать это можно следующим способом:

1. Находим по debug ключ на компьютере.
2. Копируем его на другой компьютер
3. в build.gradle прописать

   ```
   android {
       signingConfigs {
           degug {
               storeFile file("../path_to_debug_keystore")
               storePassword "android"
               keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
               keyPassword "android"
           }
       }

       buildTypes {
           debug {
               signingConfig signingConfigs.degug
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Либо можно просто попробовать скопировать с одного компьютера на другой в папку где располагается debug.keystore с заменой.

Comment: debug.keystore формируется один раз при установке AS? Я правильно понял debug.keystore  общий для всех проектов на локальной машине? Почему проблема появилась именно с этим проектом? Остальные приложения не просят переустановки на разаных ПК.

Comment: @BogdanShulga debug.keystore формируется каждый раз, когда система сборки не обнаружит его, следует учитывать что его время жизни составляет 365 дней(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#expdebug). Если не указан какой то отдельный debug ключ, то используется стандартный. По поводу того почему остальные проекты не просят переустановки сказать не могу, надо смотреть логи и настройки для конкретного проекта.

Answer (score 1):

В системе формируется дефолтный `debug.keystore`, им подписывается ваше `debug` приложение. Он сохранен в скрытом каталоге ~/.android (Место создание этого каталога, зависит от вашей системе, но обычно в профиле вашей учетной записи PC). Возьмите один из таких файлов на одном из компьютеров и замените на остальных. И тогда у вас дебаг приложение будет подписано одним ключем и не потребуется переустановка, а также не будет проблем с ключом в сторонних АПИ